# Multiple method calls on Collection.observe() event in Meteorjs

Tags: mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe

I have a 1 cursor to calculate total number of voters. I have two methods where first counts the total number of voters in my favour, second method counts the total number of voters done voting.

**LIB/collection.js**

```
infavourcount = new Mongo.Collection('infavourcount');

votedone = new Mongo.Collection('votedone');
```

**SERVER/publish.js    [count voters in my favour]**

```
function upsertInFavourCount() {
  var yes = voters.find({favour: {$regex:"Y", $options: 'i'}}).count();
  var maybe = voters.find({favour: {$regex:"M", $options: 'i'}}).count();
  var no = total - (yes + maybe);
  infavourcount.upsert('infavour',
    { 
        yes: yes ,
        maybe: maybe,
        no:no
    }
 );
}

// null name means send to all clients
Meteor.publish(null,function() {
    upsertInFavourCount();
    return infavourcount.find();
});
```

**SERVER/publish.js   [count successful votings]**

```
function upsertVoteDone() {
    var done = voters.find({voted: {$regex:"Y", $options: 'i'}}).count();
    votedone.upsert('votedone',
      { 
        done: done 
      }
   );
}

Meteor.publish(null,function() { 
    upsertVoteDone();
    return votedone.find();
});

var cursor = voters.find();

cursor.observe({
  changed: upsertVoteDone
});
```

**CLIENT/template/home.js**

```
Template.home.onCreated(function(){
   Meteor.subscribe('voters');
   Meteor.subscribe('infavourcount');
   Meteor.subscribe('votedone');
});

Template.home.helpers({
   yesvote : function() {
    return infavourcount.findOne().yes;
   },
   maybevote : function() {
    return infavourcount.findOne().maybe;
   },
   novote : function() {
    return infavourcount.findOne().no;
   },
   votedone : function() {
      return votedone.findOne().done;
   }
```

});

My problem is how to call multiple upsert methods in one observe method of  Meteor published collection.

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution by the way. The answer to this is add an function on "changed" or "added" or "removed" event and call n number of upsert methods therein.

```
cursor.observe({
  changed: function(id, fields){
    upsertInFavourCount();
    upsertVoteDone();
}
```

});